# LibGdx - NullPointerException for the default code

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, compilation, libgdx

I get these errors while compiling the default LibGdx code on my laptop. Somehow the exact same thing works on my PC.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:321)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Used the gdx setup application, generated the project for desktop only. I've added a configuration so that I can run it. And during the compiling I get this error. I haven't changed anything in the default code. Why is this happening?

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

The LwjglGraphics line in which the exception occurs is:

```
throw new GdxRuntimeException("OpenGL is not supported by the video driver: " + glVersion.getDebugVersionString(), ex3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code into desktop launcher class.

This will allow libgdx to run as software openGL mode.

```
 System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
```

Your code should look like this

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
      System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
      config.title = "Mygame"; 
      config.width = 1920;
      config.height = 1080;
      new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), config);
   }
}
```

Also update your graphic drivers.

Comment: Your code changes the error to something about my OpenGL version being too old. So yeah, it helped and probably graphics drivers will do the job.